# Grabbing Last Element From XML File

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a sample xml file like what follows.   I could have 100 entry tags containing information about each entry.  What I'm after is the final  and before  closes out the xml structure.

```
<feed xml:base="http://odata.me.com/v1/Catalog/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">Videos</title>
<id>http://odata.me.com/v1/Catalog/Videos</id>  
 <link rel="self" title="Videos" href="Videos" />

 <entry>
    <id>http://odata.me.com/v1/Catalog/Videos('AEAB20400094')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2012-05-08T19:20:08Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="VideoEf" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContentProviderEntity" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContentProviderEntity" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/ContentProviderEntity" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/VideoVersionsCollection" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="VideoVersionsCollection" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/VideoVersionsCollection" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/VideoBuyLinksCollection" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="VideoBuyLinksCollection" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/VideoBuyLinksCollection" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/VideoMetadatasCollection" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="VideoMetadatasCollection" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/VideoMetadatasCollection" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/VideoPoliciesCollection" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="VideoPoliciesCollection" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/VideoPoliciesCollection" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/GenresCollection" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="GenresCollection" href="Videos('AEAB20400094')/GenresCollection" />
    <category term="Me.Data.EF.Entities.VideoEf" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Isrc>AEAB20400094</d:Isrc>
        <d:Title>Akhasmak Ah</d:Title>
        <d:ThumbnailFilename>03FE946D8DC4D4E82A1EA56DD9EB89DA.jpg</d:ThumbnailFilename>
        <d:ContentProviderID m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:ContentProviderID>
        <d:DurationInSeconds m:type="Edm.Int32">17</d:DurationInSeconds>
        <d:CreationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2010-10-26T21:57:30.363</d:CreationDate>
        <d:ModifiedDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-05-03T20:56:42.383</d:ModifiedDate>
        <d:StartDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2009-07-13T00:00:00</d:StartDate>
        <d:EndDate m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />
        <d:CopyrightLine>(P) 2002 The copyright in this audiovisual recording is owned by Relax-In/Megastar under exclusive license to EMI Music Arabia</d:CopyrightLine>
        <d:FilteredTitle>Akhasmak Ah</d:FilteredTitle>
        <d:ThumbnailUrl>http://cache.me.com/Content/MeImages/video/03FE946D8DC4D4E82A1EA56DD9EB89DA.jpg</d:ThumbnailUrl>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
 <link rel="next" href="http://odata.me.com/v1/Catalog/Videos?$skiptoken='AUBM80800189'" />  
</feed>
```

Does anyone know how I can grab this last element..  I'm looking to get the value in href.

Ohh I'm doing this in PHP5

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath is your friend :) something like:

```
//link[@rel='next']/@href
```

I'm not sure the above xpath is exactly right (without trying it) but its something like that. It's also based on the assumption that the last link element that you are after always has the rel attribute has a value of 'next'

You'd need to use some php xpath library to use this. Some PHP Example Code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xp->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
var_dump($xp->evaluate('string(//atom:link[@rel="next"]/@href)')) ;
```

Comment: +1: It's working, need namespace registering because of the atom namespace, so probably more like: `string(//atom:link[@rel="next"]/@href)`.

Comment: Thanks hakre.  I really gotta buckle down and use xPath.

Answer (score 1):

In these same example Title can be achieved by

```
$title=$xp->evaluate('string(//atom:content/m:properties/d:Title)');
```